# Cannot run RoR site on Cloud9 due to ruby version error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloud9-ide

*Error Logs found at the bottom of this post*

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/user/codemalaysia/videos) tutorial series on how to make a Ruby on Rails application on Cloud9 but ran into a snag.

I arrived at the part where I can deploy code to the Heroku server through Cloud9. In order to do this the person of the tutorial suggested changing the Ruby version to 2.1.4 from the default 2.1.5

Deployment went fine and the site runs fine on Heroku but now I have lost the ability to run it on Cloud9. Please note that my bash_profile file has the following commands:

```
rvm use 2.1.4
source ~/.profile
```

Any ideas why I am running into this issue?

Log:

```
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin' is not at first place,                                             
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,                                            
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',                                                 
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.4'.                                                                  
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4                                                                                                          
Your code is running at https://foosite-foouser.c9.io.                                                                                 

Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin' is not at first place,                                             
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,                                            
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',                                                 
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.4'.                                                                  
Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4                                                                                                          
Your Ruby version is 2.1.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.4
```

**Update**

rvm list output:

```
foouser@foosite:~/workspace (master) $ rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.4 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
```

**Update 2**

Output from running `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`

> ```
> => Booting WEBrick
> => Rails 4.1.6 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
> => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
> => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
> => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
> [2015-04-17 21:29:28] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
> [2015-04-17 21:29:28] INFO  ruby 2.1.4 (2014-10-27) [x86_64-linux]
> [2015-04-17 21:29:28] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2626 port=8080
> ```

Comment: do you have ruby 2.1.4 installed? what's the output when you run `rvm list` on the command line?

Comment: If you're using the Rails runner, it defaults to 2.1.5@rails4, which _might_ be causing the issue. Can you try running `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` on the command line and see if the output is the same?

Comment: Terribly sorry for the late reply. Added the output in my question.

Comment: So, it works if you run rails via the command line?

Comment: Yes, indeed it does. Is there a way I can configure the IDE to do the same?

Comment: Cool! When you have the rails runner active, click on the runner and when the menu opens up, click on 'Edit Runner', Within the runner you'll see the `rvm` being setup before `rails s` is called, just set the values of the version and gemset (or remove altogether if you want the default gemset)

Comment: There is the following setting in the runner settings.

    "rvm use 2.1>/dev/null 2>&1; rvm gemset use rails4 >/dev/null 2>&1; rails server -p $port -b $ip $args"

which part do I change?

Comment: It should read something like:
`rvm use 2.1.4>/dev/null 2>&1; rails server -p $port -b $ip $args` (for your purposes, that is)

Comment: Ah silly me, I put 2.1.5 instead. The issue has been solved many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Mutahhir's suggestion, it was a matter of configuring the rails runner to 2.1.4